# prestashop is not replacing email variables

Tags: prestashop

I have following code in my mail sending script:

```
Mail::Send(intval($cookie->id_lang), 'Europcar', 'Europcar Account creation', 
                array('{name}' => $_POST['name'], 
                '{email}' => $_POST['email'], 
                '{id}' => $_POST['id'], 
                '{comment}' => nl2br($_POST['comment'])), 
                $to, 
                $_POST['name']);
```

and in email template following:

```
<tr>
        <td align="left">
            ID: {id}
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="left">
            Name: {name}
        </td>
    </tr>
```

but in emails i am getting following:

```
ID: {id}
```

I am not getting where the problem is

Answer (score 0):

Debug what happens inside of Mail class > Send method, it can help.